# Are there any good tools to generate a Google Sitemap?

Tags: asp.net, seo, sitemap

Can you recommend any tools? Should we build our own? Should we create the sitemap manually?

Comment: http://www.alreadycoded.com/seo-tools/google-xml-sitemap-generator.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Google Sitemap Generator** for IIS generates a sitemaps based on actual HTTP requests to your server (unlike other sitemap generators that rely on a crawlable path from the homepage, Google's approach doesn't actually crawl your site).

It is uniquely suited to **dynamic applications**, particularly those that have a deep bank of data that's surfaced through user queries alone.

Answer (score 2):

I have personally used Google's [sitemapgen](http://code.google.com/p/sitemap-generators/), a Python script, which automatically generates the sitemap according to an XML configuration file and a url list.

There also seems to be a newer tool called [googlesitemapgenerator](http://code.google.com/p/googlesitemapgenerator/), which according to its website is newer and supports more formats:

> Google previously released sitemapgen,
>   a Python-based tool, to Sourceforge.
>   In comparison to sitemapgen, Google
>   Sitemap Generator is a next-generation
>   tool that relies on web server
>   filtering rather than crawling,
>   provides enhanced features, and
>   supports more formats.

Answer (score 0):

I always used this one [XML-Sitemap](http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/). It's an online site thou, not a standalone application..

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you build your own if you have this ability. A sitemap should include all the files you want to be crawled and this is not always every file in the site. An automated downloadable script will likely require a decent amount of configuration to address content you do not want listed in the sitemap. 
Unless you want every file on the site spider-ed, in this case perhaps one of the scripts listed are a good option. Myself, I put a bit more effort into SEO typically and details like controlling what pages are being submitted and how is important to me.

Answer (score 0):

the big question is: how big is your site: is it <3000 pages you propably do not need any sitemap at all if all pages are linked on your site. is it <50000 you can use one of the many scripts on the internet. if it's bigger then >50000 you should make your own sitemap.xml. because then you are in the distribution SEO business where you need absolute control over your site and what you communicate to google (and when), because then you can controll: ok, i submitted google 25.000 pages, he crawled 99% of them and indexed (according to google webmaster tools) 30%, i get X visits from it, lets add another 25.000 ... and so on.

Answer (score 0):

[GSiteCrawler](http://gsitecrawler.com) is one I've used in the past and it's done me good.